# What could be the formula in excel for ni<N/2<nj

Tags: microsoft-excel

See the following set of data

```
0
0
0
3
5
6
8
```

And N/2 is 4. Anyone help me how to use formula in excel if I wants to get the lower value from the above range than 4 (ni) that will be 3 and upper value than 4 (nj) that will be 5. Can anyone tell me how to use formula in excel to auto select the upper and lower value?

Comment: Huh????????????

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you require here, this currently makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution. It may be better using VBA Macro though. This one requires you to consume additional column for checking Higher & Lower Value.

[image]